# Swift: How to create space around cells in a static UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a gap between my cells in a static UITableView. The UITableView has 3 sections, each containing 2 rows. I have tried

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

but this method does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit of a hack but it has worked for me in the past.

Simply add a UIView to the UITableViewCell and set it as a different background colour to the UITableView.

If you make the UIView smaller than the UITableViewCell, you will be able to get the desired spacing just by adding constraints.

I hope I've understood the correctly

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that UITableView does by default. There isn't a simple way to add spacing between cells, that's generally something you'd accomplish by using a UICollectionView.

If you have to use a table view you can try adding the padding into a custom UITableViewCell itself, which will create the affect you're looking for. You could also try adding additional "spacer" cells that go in between your primary content cells.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I use a UICollectionView to mimic a UITableView?